# Modal doesnt open when clicking on TouchableOpacity - React Native

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, toggle, display

I am trying to implement the modal component in this app and for some reasons, I cant make it work. I have done it in another app and even though everything looks as it should in this one, it still doesn't work, it just doesn't toggle!

Here is my code (i call `toogleModal()` here ):

```
    <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={1}
                style={styles.slideInnerContainer}
                //onPress={() => { alert(`You've clicked '${rest_name}'`); }}
                onPress={() => this.toggleModal(rest_name)}
            >
                <View style={styles.shadow} />
                <View style={[styles.imageContainer, even ? styles.imageContainerEven : {}]}>
                    {this.image}
                    <View style={[styles.radiusMask, even ? styles.radiusMaskEven : {}]} />
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.textContainer, even ? styles.textContainerEven : {}]}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        {uppercaseTitle}
                        {ratings}
                    </View>


                    <Text
                        style={[styles.subtitle, even ? styles.subtitleEven : {}]}
                        numberOfLines={2}
                    >
                        {rest_location}
                    </Text>

                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Now here is the `toggleModal()` which should set the state and then call the `onPressItem()` :

```
        toggleModal = (item) => {
        this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
        this.onPressItem(item);
    };
```

and onPressItem() :

```
    onPressItem = (item) => {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Modal animationIn="rubberBand" animationOut={"bounceOut"}

                    isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
                    onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })}
                >
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        {item}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={this.toggleModal} />
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </ThemeProvider>
        )
    };
```

Now, remember this code is taken from another app where modal is working perfectly!

Comment: Try switching your toggleModal from an arrow function. I have had some issues with calling an arrow function with an arrow function. I think it messes the scope of 'this'.

Comment: @ageoff zou mean I should create a non-arrow function and then call the togglemodal() from there?

Comment: Ya, try just a regular es5 method for `toggleMethod(item) {...}`. Then keep your arrow function in the onPress the same.

Comment: @ageoff I tried it but it doesnt work. I think there is something in this class thats stoping it to toggle, because I just tried to call that function with a button in another class and it works, but when I try the same in this class it doesnt!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your issue with click option is connected with incorrect import `TouchableOpacity` from correct module. Check if you are importing from **react-native**:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I am importing from react-native

Answer (score 0):

change this line 
 onPress={() => this.toggleModal(rest_name)}
to this:
 onPress={() => {this.toggleModal(rest_name)}}
you only need to put the function call in brackets